# iOS - Resize UILabel to match content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, resize, uilabel

I have a UILabel with linecount of 0.
I set the text for this UILabel in code.
How can I make the UILable to resize itself until it displays the full content?
I don't want to take any space unless the text is long enough to be displayed in multiple lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for `[label sizeToFit];` That will get your label to crop tight on the text you give it.